# initializing an Activity other than null

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to call a method in an onClick(). The method takeScreenShot() requires the parameter (Activity activity). My activity that I want the screenshot of is MainActivity.java. When I click the button I receive a nullpointer. I know that the Activity MainActivity has to be initialized, but I don't understand what to use other than setting it to null. It says activity on this line is null:

```
View view2 = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
```

It is called on an onClick() like so

```
public void onClick(View view) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

            Bitmap screenShot = takeScreenShot(MainActivity);
            String filename = "my_screenshot.png";
            savePic(screenShot, filename);  
                 }
            }).start();

        }
```

I don't understand how to declare and initialize

```
 Activity MainActivity;
```

before it is used in the onClick with a value other than null. If  I leave it like that it is null. How do I initialize it and what are the options I can set it = to  inorder to make it not null.

Here is the takeScreenShot method:

```
 public static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity)
{
    View view2 = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view2.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view2.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
    view2.destroyDrawingCache();
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand how to declare and initialize

You don't initialize an `Activity`. You need to send a reference to the `Activity` to this method. So from your `Activity` try

```
YourClassName.takeScreenShot(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

The onClick method provides the parameter "view" :

```
onClick(View view)
```

You should be able to get call "getParent" recursively until "parent" is an instanceOf Activity. That assumes the onClick listener is attached to the activity you want a screenshot of.